# One Page Checkout Modification Help

Tags: onepage-checkout

I have been trying to modify the sidebar of One Page Checkout to make it so that the subtotal, tax, discount codes, and grand total information display before entering your credit card number.  The reason I want to do this is we have a rewards program in which we give out a decent dollar amount promo codes and we are always getting calls because our customers are afraid that the code is invalid once they goto checkout because it's not displayed until they enter their payment information.

I have dissected our cart and have found the following. (attaching images to help get a visual).

Pre-payment-information in OPC you see this:
[image]

And the code in our checkout.xml which displays this is:

```
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar_right" as="topCartRight" template="checkout/onepage/sidebar.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="topCart.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                    <label>My Cart Extra Actions</label>
                </block>
            </block>
```

And Post-payment-information in OPC you see this:
[image]

And the code within our XML that displays that is:

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before" as="items_before" translate="label">
            <label>Items Before</label>
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after" as="items_after" translate="label">
            <label>Items After</label>
        </block>
        <block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
        <block type="core/template" name="checkout.onepage.review.button" as="button" template="checkout/onepage/review/button.phtml"/>
    </block>
```

Is there anyway to modify our cart to display the information in Post-Payment-info to display pre-payment-info?  I have spent countless hours on this and I am pretty sure it's not impossible, but I have lost direction.

Any help is greatly appreciated as always!

Comment: Anyone?  Please?

Comment: Nobody?  Someone has to have had come across this problem right?